# Как задать comment для поля типа ManyToOne в Doctrine с использованием annotations?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3, doctrine2, doctrine

Использую Symfony 3 + Doctrine ^2.5.

В какой-то момент решил завести полезную традицию добавлять к полям в БД описание (comment). 
С обычными полями, не представляющими собой связь с другой сущностью, все просто: добавляем `options={"comment":"Описание"}` и все работает, в БД добавляется коммент. Выглядит вот так:

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isNew", type="boolean", options={"comment":"Флаг Новинка"})
 */
private $isNew;
```

Сложности начинаются, когда пытаешься добавить подобную опцию к полям типа `@ORM\ManyToOne`. Полагаю, с `@ORM\ManyToMany` то же самое, но не проверял.

Добавил `options` к полю `parent` класса `Store` (склад, у склада есть родительский склад):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Store
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="store")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\StoreRepository")
 */
class Store
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var Store
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Store", inversedBy="childs", options={"comment":"Родительский склад"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $parent;

    //методы класса
}
```

после чего при вызове `doctrine:migrations:diff` получаю ошибку

> 12:20:38 ERROR     [console] Error thrown while running command "doctrine:migrations:diff". Message: "[Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinColumn declared on property AppBundle\Entity\Store::$parent does not have a property named "options". Available properties: name, referencedColumnName, unique, nullable, onDelete, columnDefinition, fieldName" ["error" => Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException { …},"command" => "doctrine:migrations:diff","message" => "[Creation Error] The annotation @ORM\JoinColumn declared on property AppBundle\Entity\Store::$parent does not have a property named "options". Available properties: name, referencedColumnName, unique, nullable, onDelete, columnDefinition, fieldName"] []

аналогичная ошибка при попытке добавить `options` к `@ORM\JoinColumn`.

Answer (score -1):

Дело в том что Вы пытаетесь добавить коммент к связи а не к физической колонке в БД.

Comment: Я это понимаю. Но где описание физической колонки БД при ManyToOne? Вы не дали ответа на вопрос.

Comment: В другой Entity с которой вы делаете связь.

Comment: Т.е. описание колонки БД этой таблицы будет в другой таблице?) Не говорите ерунды.